# Splash screen api is loading empty screen (without icon) for the very first time

Tags: android, api, splash-screen

I am facing weird issue with new splash api. I am having legacy Splashactivity as i have lot of logics added in that screen. I have followed this link (https://www.raywenderlich.com/32555180-splash-screen-tutorial-for-android) to migrate my legacy splash activity to support new splash api.

Once migration is done while launching the application from Android Studio or Installing apk for the very first time splash screen is loading without any icon(empty screen) but it works fine when i relaunch the application from application menu(mobile app list). Even though it is not working for the first time end users are affected, so if anyone have solution for this problem please help us :)

Below are my configuration

v-31 theme :

```
  <style name="AppSplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">...</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">...</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenIconBackgroundColor">...</item>
</style>
```

Splash Activity :

```
 SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
 splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition(() -> true);
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SaurabhPadwekar if you have followed all the instructions and still not working then it's sdk issue. In my case it was sdk issue, starting from AN 13 it's started working without any code change

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73919563/android-12-splash-screen-icon-not-showing-from-notification