# Android 12 Splash Screen Icon Not Showing From Notification

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-12, android-api-31

I am using the [Android 12 splash screen API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen) and while the splash screen icon shows without issue when opening the app from the launcher, opening the app from a notification only displays the splash screen background, without the icon or animated icon.

Here's the theme in `v31/styles.xml` that my activity uses in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<style name="MainActivityTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/splash_screen_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen_icon</item>
</style>
```

I also tried using this other theme, but to no avail:

```
<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/splash_screen_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_screen_icon</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/MainActivityTheme</item>
</style>
```

Any idea to make the icon visible from a notification is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After struggling with this for a while, I found out that this is the intended behavior [according to the Android team](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/205021357#comment14), although it's not clear exactly why, and people keep complaining about it. So I started looking into the new `splashScreenStyle` option in order to work around that limitation.

Basically, I just create a new activity that forwards the pending intent from the notification to the originally intended activity while requesting the splash screen icon to display.

1. Create `NotificationLaunchActivity` with theme `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent`
2. In the `onCreate()` of this activity:

   ```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(getIntent());
    Bundle options = new Bundle();
    options.putInt("android.activity.splashScreenStyle", 1);
    finish(); // Must finish the activity before
    startActivity(intent, options);
   ```
3. Replace `MainActivity.class` with `NotificationLaunchActivity.class` as the PendingIntent of your existing notification builders.

And voila, simple as that. Tested on a handful of Android 12 devices and works as expected.

**NOTE:** As far as I can tell, the same can be applied to display the splash screen icon when opening the app from deep links, system intents, as well as from [direct share targets](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive#providing-direct-share-targets).

Comment: Perfect, took me about 2 minutes to implement this fix. Thanks @S01ds!

Comment: The issue with this workaround is that it adds some dead time to app launch. Not very good experience to my opinion.

Comment: Have you tried this to open the app from app info --> Open app option, Still splash icon doesn't present